# How to use numeric time data in a for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, data-manipulation, posixct

I am trying to create a loop that will create an `ID` column in my `dataframe`, grouping the data into 5 minute intervals. I want the 5 minute point to start at the first row but I am struggling write a loop that accommodates for a large time change. I want the df to look like this:

I converted the data to numeric data but I cannot figure how to adjust the counter to accommodate for the day changing because the `300*counter` is then

```
#code that takes the numeric of POS of  and generates a watch ID based on 5 minute periods

time=c(42537.6605556, 42537.6606713, 42537.6613426, 42537.6618171, 42537.6619676, 
       42537.6648380, 42563.3838542, 42563.3839699, 42563.3840856, 42563.3842014, 
       42563.3843171, 42563.3844329, 42563.3845486)

library(openxlsx)
WatchIDfun= function(input_time){
x=(TIME=as.vector(convertToDateTime(input_time)))-TIME[1]
counter=0
n=length(x)
WatchIDOrig=c()
for (i in (1:n)){
  if (i==1){
    counter=counter+1
    WatchIDOrig[i]=counter
  } else if (x[i]/300<1){
      counter=counter
      WatchIDOrig[i]=counter
    } else if (x[i]/(300*counter)>=1&!(x[i-1]/(300*counter)>=1)){
        counter=counter+1
        WatchIDOrig[i]=counter
      } else if (x[i]/(300*counter)<1){
        counter=counter
        WatchIDOrig[i]=counter
      } else {counter=counter+1
      WatchIDOrig[i]=counter}
FINALPRODUCT= data.frame(WatchIDOrig)
assign("watchID", FINALPRODUCT, envir = .GlobalEnv)
}}
WatchIDfun(time)
```

```
WatchID=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3)
```

but instead I get

```
WatchID=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

At this point anything would help as I am very new to this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to put your data into the correct classes, `POSIXct` in this case. Then me can calculate time since the beginning in seconds, divide to get your desired interval (300), and take the floor, returning the whole number. This way we get a new group for every 300th second elapsed.

```
time <- c(42537.6605556, 42537.6606713, 42537.6613426, 42537.6618171, 42537.6619676,
          42537.6648380, 42563.3838542, 42563.3839699, 42563.3840856, 42563.3842014,
          42563.3843171, 42563.3844329, 42563.3845486)
dtf <- data.frame(time)

dtf$time <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(dtf$time, origin="1899-12-30"))

within(dtf, {
    timegroup <- cumsum(!duplicated(floor(as.numeric(time - time[1])/300)))
    })
#                   time timegroup
# 1  2016-06-16 17:51:12         1
# 2  2016-06-16 17:51:22         1
# 3  2016-06-16 17:52:20         1
# 4  2016-06-16 17:53:00         1
# 5  2016-06-16 17:53:14         1
# 6  2016-06-16 17:57:22         2
# 7  2016-07-12 11:12:45         3
# 8  2016-07-12 11:12:54         3
# 9  2016-07-12 11:13:04         3
# 10 2016-07-12 11:13:15         3
# 11 2016-07-12 11:13:24         3
# 12 2016-07-12 11:13:35         3
# 13 2016-07-12 11:13:44         3
```

Comment: Thank you so much this was so useful! I have two questions though: What does the (val=round(10*runif(length(time))) code do? I tried to run it in pieces but I cant figure it out. and Also, how could I get timegroup to be sequential integers? eg. 1 instead of 0 and 3 instead of 7408

Comment: It was just to fill the data.frame with something. I can see it being confusing, so I removed it. Also mede the groups consecutive.

Answer (score 0):

Not using a loop, but if you divide by your interval and round **UP** to the nearest integer you should get the same results. Try this replacing x with your time variable.

```
x<-1:100
WatchID<-ceiling(x/5)
WatchID
```

If you are trying to start at a number larger than 1 subtract your starting time before dividing by 5 and rounding. For instance if you wanted 4000 to 4005 to have WatchID of 1.

```
x<-4000:4100
WatchID<-ceiling((x-4000)/5)
WatchID
```